# Problems in php to add products in a shop cart

Tags: php

I have these 3 classes: `shopping cart`->`orders`->`products`.

First I add a product, when I add the second, I compare with other products in the array `products` in the object `orders`. `if count($product)==0`, then add the firs product
if `count>0`, I compare the id´s of the products in the array with the new product I want to add :

```
    public function setProduct($product,$new_quantity){
        if($this->num_product == 0) {
            $this->product[$this->num_product]=$product;
            $this->num_product++;
        } else if($this->num_product > 0) {
            for($i=0; $i < $this->num_product; $i++) {
                if($this->product[$i]->getIdproduct() == $product->getIdproduct()) {
                    $this->product[$i]->setQuantity($this->product[$i]->getquantity()+$new_quantity);
                    break;
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
                $this->product[$this->num_product]=$product;
                $this->num_product++;
            }

        }
    }
```

When I finish the comparison, I have to add these new product but this doesn't work. What is my mistake?

Comment: Define "doesn't work". Do you get an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your method is really complicated for what you want to do.

First of all, `$this->num_product` is exactly the same thing as `count($this->product)`. So why use a variable to hold this information ?

Second of all, no need to separate the case of zero products and some products in the cart, the `for` loop won't execute if there's no product in the cart.

I propose this as a solution :

```
public function setProduct($product,$new_quantity){
   for($i=0; $i < count($this->product); $i++) {
        if($this->product[$i]->getIdproduct() == $product->getIdproduct()) {
            $this->product[$i]->setQuantity($this->product[$i]->getquantity() + $new_quantity);
            return; // we found our product, get out of the function.
        }
   }
   // the product was not found in the array, add it to the end
   $this->product[]=$product;
}
```

If you want to keep your code, I think the mistake is that you add the product to the array at each iteration of the loop (the last two lines of the loop, after the `if` clause), but it's really hard to say without some explanation about what you think is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that the last two lines of the the `for` loop will never get executed. If the `if` contidion is `true` it will `break` the loop, otherwise will `continue` without ever reaching these two lines. The easiest way is to use `retun` if your function doesn't do anything after the loop.

```
 public function setProduct($product,$new_quantity){
        if($this->num_product == 0) {
            $this->product[$this->num_product]=$product;
            $this->num_product++;
        } else if($this->num_product > 0) {
            for($i=0; $i < $this->num_product; $i++) {
                if($this->product[$i]->getIdproduct() == $product->getIdproduct()) {
                    $this->product[$i]->setQuantity($this->product[$i]->getquantity()+$new_quantity);
                    return;
                }
            }
            $this->product[$this->num_product]=$product;
            $this->num_product++;
        }
    }
```

See also what `@krtek` says about the need of no checking for 0 elements